# Applying function on a value returned from MarkupExtension in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is there a way to apply a function on a value returned from a MarkupExtenstion such as

{Binding ... } or {StaticResource ...} in XAML?

Usage example: making the font size of button1 to be twice bigger than the font size of button2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  You would have to make a custom [markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747254.aspx) that does this.

[Here's an example that evaluates a Python/Ruby script via a markup extension.](http://www.thinkbottomup.com.au/site/blog/Embedding_DLR_Scripts_in_XAML_Part_2)